# How to model a basket?

Tags: modeling

I really don't know how to make this type of fishing basket, just the net without the fishes

[image]

Someone more expert knows how to?

Comment: This is a site run by volunteers answering question for free on their spare time, rushing them or giving deadlines may be discouraging and is generally considered rude. Among other factors, how fast you get answers depends largely on how thorough your question is. Instead of digressing about deadlines provide factual details to diagnose the issue, [add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), state what you have tried and what research you did about it. Otherwise may be best to seek professional help.

Comment: Hello maybe this tutorial will help: https://youtu.be/FIk-884zKoo

Comment: Hi Letz Pro, all I see is fish :). Please edit your question and provide a better reference(s) of the object you want to model or even better - a making of video of the basket. Let us know how experienced are you with 3D modeling and how close to the real object the model should be.

Comment: Should be a low poly version of if Rumen but the tutorial that moonboots sent resolved the problem. Thanks for the help :)